# In Postgres, is it possible for me to have a table partitioning constraint based on data type?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, check-constraints

Say I have the following schema for my Postgres database:

```
CREATE TABLE sources (
  source  TEXT  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (source)
);

CREATE TABLE ipaddrs (
  addr  INET
) INHERITS (source):

CREATE TABLE domains (
  domain  TEXT
) INHERITS (source);
```

Is it possible for me to use a `CHECK` constraint somewhere that would add a `source` that is a valid IP address to the `ipaddrs` partition, and otherwise add it  to the `domains` partition?

Ultimately, I'm wanting to be able to leverage Postgres' built-in INET/CIDR capabilities on sources that are IP addresses.

Comment: Perhaps this is better achieved by adding a trigger function to `sources` that checks to see if the source being added is a valid IP address... if so, inserting it into `ipaddrs`, otherwise inserting it into `domains`?

Comment: do you need ipv6 support?